# Are there specific consequences of modifying a parent Array from a child component?

Tags: javascript, arrays, pointers, vue.js

It is possible to modify parents properties from within a child component when the `props` are an Array:

```js
Vue.component('search-box', {
  template: '#search-box-template',
  props: ['who']
})
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#root',
  data: {
    who: ['a', 'b']
  }
})
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.3/vue.js"></script>

<div id="root">
  who as seen by the parent: {{who}}
  <search-box v-bind:who="who"></search-box>
</div>

<template id="search-box-template">
    <div>
        who as seen by the child: {{who}}
    <button v-on:click="who.push('x')">modify who from within the child</button>
    </div>
</template>
```

Beside the intended action to modify the parent from a child (which may be, style wise, a bad thing to do) - **are there collateral consequences of doing so, ones which would break Vue.js?**

Comment: You can emit an event from child, listen on parent and perform mutation in parent using a method.

Comment: @wostex: yes, I know about prop/event communication between parents and children components -- I was wondering whether the action in my question would have unintended consequences.

Comment: @wostex how would you 'emit' an event? What am I missing here?

Comment: Changing props directly in your child is a bad practice because props are passed from parent and can/will overwrite your changes. This is why common practice is to mutate the data inside parent component (the one which holds this data) so that updated data passes again as a prop.

Comment: @Dellirium docs with examples: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Custom-Events

Comment: @wostex: but in my case the data changed inside the child is directly the parent's data as well (the same data). No matter where they change, they are the same in both parent and children (and are held, to take your comment, by the parent).

Comment: Probably I don't understand your question correctly then.

Comment: @wostex: no, I rather think I was not clear - having started with Vue.js only recently and coming from Python. What I mean is that the Array passed to the child is a pointer, so all the changes in that array (whether in the child or in the parent) are updated on one single copy of the data, held by the parent.I was wondering if this would not be otherwise dangerous. (BTW, I am also looking at the event emission you mentioned, which is the documented way to pass info from the child to the parent - but is more difficult to understand for me)

Comment: Well, indeed, you can do in Vue whatever you can do in Javascript in general, but it's a rule of thumb that you don't directly update parent state from within a child. Though Vue doesn't forbid it, if you want to take this approach. Prop-event pair is usually more clear and easy to understand when you look at the parent component for example. But it's not required in case you're ok with another approach in case of reference types as arrays/objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not "break Vue" by breaking encapsulation, and that's what updating a component's data items from outside the component is. The [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Composing-Components) say

> it is also very important to keep the parent and the child as
> decoupled as possible via a clearly-defined interface. This ensures
> each component’s code can be written and reasoned about in relative
> isolation, thus making them more maintainable and potentially easier
> to reuse.

That is the rationale: it's good programming, not a matter of being something Vue cannot handle.